# Is there any study in strong plurivalent logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Logic is often depicted as having two truth values (true and false, 1 and 0). Can you provide an example of strong fixed logic (with no intermediate or unknown truth values) that uses three or more elements? What I mean by this is: Is there any logic system with 3 or more complementary truth values?

Comment: There are several three-valued logics out there; why are they not satisfactory? (That is, what precisely is an intermediate or unknown truth value? We may *interpret* the third truth value in a certain way, but I don't see obviously how that's *intrinsic* to the logic itself ...)

Comment: For example, there's ternary (or higher) Post logic, where negation behaves "cyclically:" e.g. in the three-valued version we have three truth values $a,b,c$ and negation satisfies $\neg a=b$, $\neg b=c$, $\neg c=a$. Does that count?